# How to bind drop down menu with toggle group

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a drop-down menu with four options, and I also have how toggles, and I want to make it so when I select a certain option, I turn on a certain toggle. It's mostly just to try to figure out the drop-down menu.  I just want to find out how to say, when an option is selected, this happens.

I declared a list in the code

```
List<string> encryptions = new List<string>() { "Normal", "L337", "Character Shift", "DoubleCase", "No Vowels" };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here:**

[image]

## HOW TO:

**Create a DropDown and add the options which you mentioned in your list:**

[image]

**Add the following script on this gameObject:**

```
public class DropDownToToggle : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Toggle[] toggles;

    public void OnDropDownValueChanged(int index)
    {
        if ( toggles.Length == 0 || index > toggles.Length)
        {
            return; // Toggles are not assigned from inspector.
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < toggles.Length; i++)
        {
            toggles[i].isOn = (i == index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Assign event handler to OnValueChanged in dropdown:**

[image]

**Create a toggle group and toggles under it accordingly:**

[image]

**Add toggle group component to toggle group object and vertical layout group (optional):**

[image]

**Assign toggles in toggles array of script in inspector:**

[image]

And you are good to go

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The InputField has the OnValueChanged event. It can pass a Int32 but this one is static. What you need is the value of the input field.

First you need an input field reference to your item, and then you use it when the event is called:

```
public InputField inputField = null;

public void OnValueChanged(Int32 i)
{
    int value = this.inputField.value;
    switch(value){
        case 0:
           break;
        case 1:
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do, but I think I understand that you want to detect when the dropdown is changed. To do that, simply use the `On Value Changed` from the Unity Inspector window. You'll need to first make a function in your script, then attach it in the inspector. [Read here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html) for more details.